# Insert random number into table upon new record creation

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I would like to store random numbers in one MySql table, randomly retrieve one and insert it into another table column each time a new record is created. I want to delete the retrieved number from the random number table as it is used.

The random numbers are 3 digit, there are 900 of them.

I have read several posts here that describe the problems using unique random numbers and triggering their insertion. I want to use this method as it seems to be reliable while generating few problems.

Can anyone here give me an example of a sql query that will accomplish the above? (If sql query is not the recommended way to do this please feel free to recommend a better method.)

Thank you for any help you can give.

I put together the two suggestions here and tried this trigger and query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER rand_num before 
INSERT ON uau3h_users FOR EACH ROW 
insert into uau3h_users (member_number) 
select random_number from uau3h_rand900 
where random_number not in (select member_number from uau3h_users) 
order by random_number 
limit 1
```

But it seems that there is already a trigger attached to that table so the new one cause a conflict, things stopped working until I removed it. Any ideas about how accomplish the same using another method?

Answer (score 1):

You are only dealing with 900 records, so performance is not a major issue.

If you are doing a single insert into a table, you can do something like the following:

```
insert into t(rand)
    select rand
    from rand900
    where rand not in (select rand from t)
    order by rand()
    limit 1
```

In other words, you don't have to continually delete from one table and move to the other.  You can just choose to insert values that don't already exist.  If performance is a concern, then indexes will help in this case.

Comment: The new record is created in a users table each time someone registers for an event. One random number will be assigned to each new user for later use. I would need to make sure that duplicate numbers are not assigned, thus the need to delete the assigned number from the pool.

Comment: What's your plan for when you use up all your numbers?

Comment: The numbers can be reused from event to event so that won't present a problem.

Comment: And I want to thank those who made suggestions already. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you need to take a look into Triggers. You can do some stuff for instance after inserting a record in a table. Refer this link to more details. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: Thank you for the trigger reference. Please see the above comment for what I did with the info.